# scala : Getting play.api.data.Form[String] required: Option[models.User]

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I'm getting play.api.data.Form[String] required: Option[models.User] when trying to display error in html view.

Below is the code I'm trying to use, please feel free to reedit everything if needed. Thanks

Controller :

```
  val forgotPasswordForm = Form(
    single(
      "email" -> text
    ) verifying ("Invalid email or password", result => result match {
      case (e) => User.findOneByEmail(e).isDefined
    })
  )

  def forgotPassword() = withOptionUser { user => implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.anon.forgotPassword(user))
  }

  def forgotPasswordSubmit = withOptionUser { user: User => implicit request =>
    forgotPasswordForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        // do something with the bad form, like reshow the view
        BadRequest(views.html.anon.forgotPassword(formWithErrors))
      },
      submission => {
        // do something with the submitted form
        Ok("got " + forgotPasswordForm.value)
      }
    )
  }
```

Html :

```
@(  user:   Option[User]
)

@stylesheet = {
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.at("styles/public/anon.min.css")'>
}

@main("Forgot Password",user: Option[User],"forgotPassword",stylesheet){

<section class="login">
    <div class="loginBox contentBox">
        <h1>Forgot Password?</h1>

        @if(forgotPasswordForm.hasGlobalErrors) {
            <ul>
            @forgotPasswordForm.globalErrors.foreach { error =>
                <li>error.message</li>
            }
            </ul>
        }

        <p>Enter your email address:</p>
        <form action="/forgotpassword" method="POST">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" id="email" data-xpl="loginEmail"/>

            <div class="greenButton">
                <input type="submit" id="loginbutton" value="submit" data-xpl="loginSubmit"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

}
```

Comment: Thanks @biesior I did not notice the wrong tag "playback"

Comment: although we guess that's Play 2+ with Scala, you could add info about concrete version in tags/question.

Comment: thanks biesior.. will do that

Answer (score 1):

`formWithErrors` is a `Form[String]`, and your template is expecting `Option[User]`. I don't entirely understand why you're passing `Option[User]` to your forgot password form, but that template will need to have `forgotPasswordForm: Form[String]` in the parameter list.

Then you can render the template like this:

```
Ok(views.html.anon.forgotPassword(user, forgotPasswordForm))
```

or

```
BadRequest(views.html.anon.forgotPassword(user, formWithErrors))
```